# Change size of math symbols

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

What is the matter with `$\tilde{\scriptsize{\mathscr{O}}}$`?
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show a complete example? And also tell why you want this.

Comment: I just have to use both $\mathscr{O}$ and a smaller $\mathscr{O}$.

Answer (score 4):

## Remarks

You need to use `\scriptstyle` rather than `\scriptsize` in math mode. Also keep in mind that `\scriptstyle` takes no arguments, but changes the style inside the current group. See also p. 292, Chapter 26 in the TeXbook.

## Implementation

Compile with any plain TeX engine

```
$\tilde{\cal O}$
$\tilde{\scriptstyle {\cal O}}$
$\tilde{\scriptscriptstyle {\cal O}}$
\bye
```

## Output

> [image]